# Project Euler #8 -- Javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
/***
 * Problem 8 -- Largest Product in a Series
 *
 * @author RepeaterCreeper
 */

var grid = `73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
    96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
    85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
    12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
    66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
    62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
    30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
    70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
    65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
    52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
    53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
    83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
    82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
    16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
    17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
    24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
    07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
    84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
    05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
    71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450`;

/**
 * Largest Adjacent Numbers
 * 
 * @returns int
 */
function largestAdjacentNumbers(grid, consecutiveLength = 4, separator = "\n") {
  let gridData = grid.split("\n"),
    largestProduct = 0;

  for (var row in gridData) {
    currentRow = gridData[row].split('').map(x => parseInt(x));

    for (var i = 0; i < currentRow.length - consecutiveLength; i++) {
      combination = currentRow.slice(i, i + consecutiveLength);
      if (!combination.includes(0)) {
        product = combination.reduce(function(a, b) {
          return a * b
        });
        if (largestProduct < product) largestProduct = product;
      }
    }
  }

  return largestProduct;
}

console.log(largestAdjacentNumbers(grid, 13));
```

## Issue:

So the issue the fact that no matter what I do, my code is stuck at getting: 
**5377010688**

The correct answer is:
**23514624000**


As you can see that's a MASSIVE difference. If I simply do a 4-adjacent number in the grid, it works as it matches the solution given for the 4-adjacent number example. Which is:


**5832**

---

I've definitely looked into some other SO questions that relate to Problem 8 of Project Euler, but none of them seem to match my issue. If I did somehow miss one, a link would be nice. Though I do doubt that as I literally went through a good bit of SO questions before posting this.

---

## Problem States:

https://projecteuler.net/problem=8 -- Link to Problem

> The four adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product are 9 × 9 × 8 × 9 = 5832.
>
> 73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
>   96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
>   85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
>   12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
>   66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
>   62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
>   30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
>   70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
>   65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
>   52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
>   53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
>   83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
>   82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
>   16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
>   17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
>   24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
>   07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
>   84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
>   05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
>   71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450
>
> Find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product. What is the value of this product?

Comment: What are you calling it with that gives you `5377010688`?

Comment: I don't see how your code does columns at all. Do diagonales count?

Comment: @ASDFGerte For this specific question, it's just doing horizontal so left and right. The problem that does that specifies that it wants up, down, right, left and diagonals.

Comment: So the end of line has no meaning? Your code always cuts off at the end of the line though?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Edited the code to output wrong output .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question says:

> The four adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product are 9 × 9 × 8 × 9 = 5832.
>
> (some number over multiple lines, 1000 digits long)
>
> Find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product. What is the value of this product?

It's not asking you to iterate over each *row* - it's asking you to interpret the whole thing as one string (or number) and compare adjacent digits. Turn the `grid` into a single string initially, and your code works as expected:

```js
var grid = `73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450`
    .split('\n').join('');

/**
 * Largest Adjacent Numbers
 * 
 * @returns int
 */
function largestAdjacentNumbers(grid, consecutiveLength = 4, separator = "\n") {
  let gridData = grid.split("\n"),
    largestProduct = 0;

  for (var row in gridData) {
    currentRow = gridData[row].split('').map(x => parseInt(x));

    for (var i = 0; i < currentRow.length - consecutiveLength; i++) {
      combination = currentRow.slice(i, i + consecutiveLength);
      if (!combination.includes(0)) {
        product = combination.reduce(function(a, b) {
          return a * b
        });
        if (largestProduct < product) largestProduct = product;
      }
    }
  }

  return largestProduct;
}

console.log(largestAdjacentNumbers(grid, 13));
```

But it would be good to remove the part that iterates over each row now that there are no rows or newlines in the input, and to fix the off-by-one error, as noted in comment:

```js
var grid = `73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450`;
var gridData = grid.split('\n').join('').split('').map(Number);
/**
 * Largest Adjacent Numbers
 * 
 * @returns int
 */
function largestAdjacentNumbers(grid, consecutiveLength = 4, separator = "\n") {
  let largestProduct = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i <= gridData.length - consecutiveLength; i++) {
    combination = gridData.slice(i, i + consecutiveLength);
    if (!combination.includes(0)) {
      const product = combination.reduce(function(a, b) {
        return a * b
      });
      if (largestProduct < product) largestProduct = product;
    }
  }

  return largestProduct;
}

console.log(largestAdjacentNumbers(grid, 13));
```

Comment: `i < gridData.length - consecutiveLength`, that's an off-by-one i originally made too. The easiest example to see this is when `length` is exactly 13, it wouldn't do anything at all even though it should run once.

Answer (score 0):

The problem apparently doesn't intend that the end of line has any meaning. Here is code that produces the desired result.

```js
let str = `73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450`;
str = str.replace(/\n/g, "");

let max = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < str.length - 12; i++) {
 let part = str.substr(i, 13);
 let currentProduct = 1;
 for (let n of part) {
  currentProduct *= +n;
 }
 max = Math.max(max, currentProduct);
}

console.log(max);
```